# Why is my object lying on the surface when I export file as OBJ?

Tags: objects, export, blend-files, windows

I've made a 3D model (a snowman). I've saved it as a BLEND file and it was standing. After that I wanted to export it as an OBJ file. I viewed it in Microsoft Print 3D and it was lying. How can I fix that so my snowman will stand?
[image: Snowman is standing in Blender]
[image: Snowman is lying in Print 3D]

Answer (score 4):

On the left side of the exporter window, there is an option for it.[image]

Comment: Thumb up. That is highly worth remembering.